# Sum of two numbers $x, y = 1050$. What is the maximum value of the HCF between $x$ and $y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

Let $HCF (x, y) = h$ then we can say that $x=ha$ and $y=hb$ for some multiple of $h$ i.e. $a$ and $b$ respectively and where $ HCF(a,b)=1$ .

As per question :-
$x+y = 1050$
$\Rightarrow ha+hb = 1050$
$\Rightarrow h(a+b) = 1050$

Now taking $h$ as maximum i.e. $1050$, then $a+b =1$ which means that either $a=0$ and $b=1$ or $a=1$ and $b=0$ and we can also see that that $HCF(a,b) = 1$ in both the cases which is valid. Then shouldn't the answer for the maximum HCF be 1050 ? Need clarification with this one please.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is HCF in the question?

Comment: I agree with your answer.  However: if the question required $x,y \ge 1$, then your answer with a $0$ woud not be allowed.

Comment: @Ganit Are there are restrictions on $x$ and $y$, e.g., both must be positive integers? If there's this condition, for example, then $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi HCF stands for "Highest Common Factor", which is also commonly called gcd (greatest common divisor).

Comment: @All : I have put up the exact question as it has been provided on the textbook from where I have picked up the question.

Comment: there are no restrictions mentioned in the question.

Comment: as per your comments, it looks like that might be question provided in the textbook might be incomplete.

Comment: Which textbook did you get this from ? @Ganit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the answer is $1050$, supposing both x and y are non-negative

If we consider $x>y$

$HCF(x;y)\le x$

So if we choose for $x$ any number less than $1050$, the $HCF$ will be strictly less than $1050$, and if we take any number greater than $1050$, $y$ would be negative.

Comment: I don't see why you need to assume that $x,y$ are nonnegative. A common divisor of $x$ and $y$ will also be a divisor of their sum, which is $1050$, and the greatest divisor of $1050$ is $1050$.